# Generating link to full map with MX Google Maps

Tags: mx-google-map

I have MX Google Maps working fine on a per-entry basis, but I'd like to give the user an option to view the full map on Google Maps.

This doesn't work:

```
<p>{the-map}
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q={title}+{address}+{city}+
{state}+{zipcode}@{latitude},{longitude}" target="_blank">
Full-size Google Map</a>
{/the-map}
```

Ideas why?

Comment: What does it output...?

Comment: Can you post URLs where we can browse the working and non-working output? Also, what exactly doesn't work -- what's missing / broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what about your example doesn't work, but you don't need your link to contain so much information if you don't need it to. Simply using the longitude / latitude is enough to get your location up in Google Maps.

For example [Tower Bridge, London](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.505591,-0.075402) can be linked just using:

`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.505591,-0.075402`

So with your example it'd be:

```
<p>{the-map}
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q={latitude},{longitude}" target="_blank">
Full-size Google Map</a>
{/the-map}
```

If after all that, it's your MX Google Map tags that aren't outputting correctly then this will be of no help what so ever!

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to try a different map solution, as I'm seeing a glitch with icon placement.